# Creating a mini-site that works on Blackberry

Tags: asp.net, mobile

Yesterday i got a requirement from my senior saying that they want to view pages which are in asp that should be properly rendered on BlackBerry device. I know it will work but it will ugly... but after googling i have found about asp.net mobile pages that will work for my requirement..... but are there any more options available which will reduce my development effort.

regards,

Rick Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference in what language the site is programmed in. How the client (in this case a phone) interprets it is entirely based on what it is sent: html, css, and javascript. One popular client-side framework for mobile development is http://jquerymobile.com/. Its goal is to:

> unify user interface system across all popular mobile device
>   platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI foundation.

To see a great example of mobile/responsive design: go to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/, and change your browser width in and out. Notice how page elements move around based on your screen size? There are different css rules that apply based on the max-width of the browser window. So the solution is baked right into the site.

Other than a framework, the foundation of mobile development is creating semantically correct (and not too verbose) markup that a mobile browser can parse. This means good classic html, small optimized images, percentage based sizes, etc..

Smashing magazine has a great round-up of intro -> advanced articles on modern mobile development : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/guidelines-for-mobile-web-development/

Comment: Hey Michael Jasper thanks for your reply..... i will have a look over JqueryMobile but i have found about Asp.Net Mobile Website and Asp.Net MVC Mobile.... Can any 1 tell how me how can i start with Asp.Net Mobile Website I am trying to find Mobile Templates But not able to find one...... and 2nd are there any video tutorials for step by step start with MobileWebsite in Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

In case that you havn't found the material, this is [asp.net mvc 4 mobile features tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features).

You can also watch the [video tutorial from Phil](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-803T)